# Is it possible to hide/remove borders inside of intersected area of multiple divs?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

When two or more `div`'s intersect they just overlap and their borders are visible:

```css
.circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#two {
  left: 50px;
}

#three {
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div >
  <div class="circle" id="one"></div>
  <div class="circle" id="two"></div>
  <div class="circle" id="three"></div>
</div>
```

The question is if it's possible to hide those border, that are inside of the intersected area so it looks like there is only one big shape. Taking the example above the result should look like this:

[image]

Comment: You might be able to get at least halfway there with specifying a z-index otherwise the border CSS attributes usually only apply to up, down, left, and right. You can hide only one part of a border with something like "border-left: hidden;" but it might not work quite how you want with this.

Comment: If there is an answer anywhere it would very likely be here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/circle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using `mask` and adjust the code slightly to have better control. The trick is to use multiple mask where each one will be a circular gradient that will show only the border and each gradient will overlap each circle element. You can control the overlap using margin on the center element:

```css
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  transition:0.5s;
}

.box {
  display:inline-flex;
  -webkit-mask:
     radial-gradient(50px at 52px              50%,transparent 99%,#fff 100%),
     radial-gradient(50px at 50%               50%,transparent 99%,#fff 100%),
     radial-gradient(50px at calc(100% - 52px) 50%,transparent 99%,#fff 100%);
  mask:
     radial-gradient(50px at 52px              50%,transparent 99%,#fff 100%),
     radial-gradient(50px at 50%               50%,transparent 99%,#fff 100%),
     radial-gradient(50px at calc(100% - 52px) 50%,transparent 99%,#fff 100%);
  -webkit-mask-composite: source-in;
  mask-composite: intersect;
}

body {
  background:linear-gradient(to right,pink,yellow);
}

/* You can also have animation*/
.box:hover .circle{
   margin:0!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle" style="margin:0 -50px;"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="box">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle" style="margin:0 -30px;"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="box">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle" style="margin:0 -70px;"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="box">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle" style="margin:0 -10px;"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

[image: CSS hide intersection border]

And with CSS variables to have better control:

```css
.circle {
  width: calc(2*var(--r));
  height: calc(2*var(--r));
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: var(--b) solid black;
}

.box {
  --r:50px; /* radius of circles*/
  --b:2px;  /* border length */
  --g:transparent 99%,#fff 100%;
  
  display:inline-flex;
  -webkit-mask:
     radial-gradient(var(--r) at calc(var(--r) + var(--b))        50%,var(--g)),
     radial-gradient(var(--r) at 50%                              50%,var(--g)),
     radial-gradient(var(--r) at calc(100% - var(--r) - var(--b)) 50%,var(--g));
  mask:
     radial-gradient(var(--r) at calc(var(--r) + var(--b))        50%,var(--g)),
     radial-gradient(var(--r) at 50%                              50%,var(--g)),
     radial-gradient(var(--r) at calc(100% - var(--r) - var(--b)) 50%,var(--g));
  -webkit-mask-composite: source-in;
  mask-composite: intersect;
}

body {
  background:linear-gradient(to right,pink,yellow);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle" style="margin:0 -50px;"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="box" style="--r:40px;--b:5px;">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle" style="margin:0 -30px;"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="box" style="--r:100px;--b:20px;">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle" style="margin:0 -70px;"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="box" style="--r:80px;--b:5px;">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle" style="margin:0 -10px;"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

[image: CSS remove intersection area]

Answer (score 2):

As per your first query this is not possible to make intersect border invisible using CSS. However, if you want to achieve above design you can pseudo element trick to achieve this. You can create pseudo element to "#two" id and make it position absolute relative to the height and width of center div. You need to make little bit adjustment for sure. I have added snippet for you. Please try it.

```css
.circle {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            border: 1px solid black;
          }

          #two {
            left: 50px;
            background: #fff;
          }

          #two:after {
            content: "";
            background: #fff;
            width: 100%;
            height: 88px;
            top: 6px;
            left: -2px;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 9;
            -ms-transform: rotate(20deg);
            transform: rotate(.2deg);
          }

          #three {
            left: 100px;
            background: #fff;
          }
```

```html
<div >
  <div class="circle" id="one"></div>
  <div class="circle" id="two"></div>
  <div class="circle" id="three"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

another possibilitie is [`mix-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode) if avalaible:

```css
 /* === HERE ==== comment where it matters , the rest is only styling */
div {
  width: 20vmax;
  height: 20vmax;
  border: solid;
  background: white;/* === HERE ====*/
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  font-size:4vmax;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  box-shadow:0 0 10px, inset 0 0 2px;
  animation:shift 4s infinite ease-in-out alternate;
}
div::before,
div::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  background: inherit;
  border: inherit;
  border-radius: inherit;
  box-shadow:inherit;
  mix-blend-mode:screen;/* === HERE ====*/
  animation:shift 2s infinite ease-in-out alternate;
}
div::before {
  left:-50%;
}
div::after {
  left:50%;
  animation-delay:-1s;
}
p {z-index:1;}
@keyframes shift {
25% {transform:translate(5%,-5%) scale(1.2);}
50% {transform:translate(-5%,5%) scale(0.9);}
}
html {display:flex;min-height:100vh;}
body {margin:auto;}
```

```html
<div><p>Hi, Cloudy</p></div>
```

[demo for the fun](https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/MWwKRvO)

Comment: If we consider the fact that the border will always be black I would use `lighten` for the mix-blend-mode and this will work whataver the coloration you will be using as background.